# HTML table, is there a way to to drop the second column to a new line?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a table with 5 columns in it, trouble is the 1 st column `<td>` values can be long and thus get crammed up. Is there a way to move the second column to a newline and span the first column over the entire row without creating a new row `<tr>` for the first column

thanks

Comment: a table row is what it says, a row, you are dealing with `td` (table data, or "cells"), these come one after the other in an horizontal fashion, I don't see a way to do what you request without resorting to divs or a tableless structure.

Comment: This is not what i want as ive written above the reason is because i have a background gradient applied to each row and i dint what the "top" row to have its own gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `td`'s can be stacked vertically that way.. Perhaps rather than using `td`'s, you could separate them into `div`'s, messing with the CSS would put them in line, and when the first one stretches to big, it should push the other one below it?

EDIT 2: Newer version, better aligning.

```
<table style="width: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background-color: red; display: inline;">
                OneOneOneOne
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: blue; display: inline; width: 90px;">
                TwoTwoTwo
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: green; display: inline; width: 90px;">
                Three
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background-color: red; display: inline;">
                OneOneOneOneOneOneOneOneOneOneOne
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: blue; display: inline; width: 90px;">
                TwoTwoTwo
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: green; display: inline; width: 90px;">
                Three
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Not pretty looking, and would need some more tweaks, but it is something like what you described..

Comment: Thanks Sachleen, I am still trying to catch onto the formatting.

Comment: No worries, for some reason the text wasn't showing for me at all. It was just `believe 's can` and `using 's, you` so that's why I edited but after I checked the revision it looked OK. Not sure if it was just something weird or if you tried to fix it at the same time or what.

Comment: There's no point in using a table at all, in your example. You can just use the divs with some clear fix.

Comment: You are correct, in both your comments. I tried to edit it, and the table is pointless.

Comment: This approach could work but its very difficult to get the divs to line up unless I fix the widths rather then use %

Comment: I changed the code to a bit. This might work out better for you, as the other columns can be set widths, and the first will flex itself along.

I suppose if you want column 1 to stretch 100% if the content is long enough to knock one div down so that it knocks all of them down, you could use jQuery to check is width, once over a certain width set it to 100% or something.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to make a new `tr` (table *row*) for the second *row* and you can make the first one wider with the `colspan` attribute.

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">abcdefg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```